# Sending data to another C++ application

Tags: c++, sockets, send

I am working on GPS output. I have managed to extract the latitude, longitude, time and date from a NMEA sentence. I have the data in variables and now I want to send the extracted data to another C++ program which will receive these variables and display them as output on the same computer. How do I go about doing it? I've researched and heard that I could use sockets but I don't know how to do it. The data I have is in floats and integers.

Comment: You should check Boost.ASIO -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: just a socket tutorial (in c) http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/

Comment: Using sockets is one option, but you could also use a higher level messaging abstraction like ZeroMQ (http://zeromq.org/)

Comment: Google for "inter process communications". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication